# Cast iron sewer pipe leak? Or something else? Shower pan?

Tags: plumbing, shower, leak, sewer, slab

We have a concrete slab and it’s soaked. Water has been coming up through the grout of our ceramic tile. This may have been something that happened over time and we only noticed now. We had a few plumbers inspect with a camera and we got different opinions. I’m hoping someone here might be able to help.

1) We have confirmed there’s no water line break as the meter doesn’t move when we are not using water.

2) Plumber #1 sent in a camera and thinks there’s an offset at the joint of the drain pipe. He is convinced that that is the source of the leak.

The sewer line is 4 feet down the slab.

3) Plumber #2 says he didn’t see any problem there other than some build up. He also pointed out that it would take a lot of water pressure and fighting gravity for it to come up this way.

4) We don’t have any clogs whatsoever.

Thoughts? Is it possible to have a slow leak at the joint, say, over years, for all that water to build up, without other symptoms like a clogged drain?

One other suspicion I have is a possible leak from our shower. But all our walls/baseboards are dry and we never noticed water on our flooring. I don’t know how it would be possible for the shower water to only go down to our foundation and spread under our flooring versus floating out from the top of our tiles?

Comment: What is your subsoil?  If you are built on heavy clay, I can easily believe the only way for the water to go is up; if you are built on sandy gravel, that's a lot less plausible.

Comment: What is the water level in the soil outside your house?

Comment: Hmm, I never thought to check to see how wet the soil is outside. The house was built almost 50 years ago and the area is not prone to any flooding etc

Comment: We moved in about 2 years ago. And if there’s a leak, we don’t know when it started.

Comment: Where do you live? Are sinkholes or underground springs common in your area?

Comment: No not common at all. And I have not heard anything from neighbors.

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please [register](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts. Thanks, and welcome to the site!